# Perl: open/close capturing return code

Tags: perl

myb.py

```
import time
import sys


stime = time.time()
run_until = 600

cnt = 0
while True:
    dur = time.time() - stime
    if dur > run_until:
        break

    cnt += 1
    print cnt
    time.sleep(1)

    if cnt == 10:
        sys.exit(2)            <---- capture 2
```

mya.pl

```
use FileHandle;

my $myexe = 'myb.py';
my $FH = FileHandle->new;
open $FH, q{-|},
    "$myexe 2>&1"
    or print "Cannot open\n";
process_output($FH);
close $FH or warn $!;

sub process_output {
    my ($fh) = @_;

    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        print "$line\n";
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Warning: something's wrong at ./mya.pl line 10.
```

if i change the line to:

```
my $err = close $FH;
```

it gives me a blank for $err.

Question: How can I capture the return code 2 from myb.py in mya.pl?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html states that `close` returns `false`. It doesn't have to be a `0`. A blank *is* `false` in perl, I guess.

Comment: @g.tsh yeah i got that part. but i want to specifically capture '2.' not true or false. is that not doable with open/close combination?

Comment: I've used capture_exec: http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/IO-CaptureOutput-1.1103/lib/IO/CaptureOutput.pm to get stdout and exit code. I don't know how to achieve this with plain `open`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `open` creates a child, `close` functions as `waitpid` and sets `$?` accordingly.

```
$ perl -e'
   open(my $fh, "-|", @ARGV)
      or die $!;

   print while <$fh>;

   close($fh);
   if    ($? == -1 ) { die $!; }
   elsif ($? & 0x7F) { die "Killed by signal ".($? & 0x7F)."\n"; }
   elsif ($? >> 8  ) { die "Exited with error ".($? >> 8)."\n"; }
' perl -E'
   $| = 1;
   for (1..5) {
      say;
      sleep 1;
   }
   exit 2;
'
1
2
3
4
5
Exited with error 2
```

Answer (score 5):

As documented in http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html, the exit value is available as part of [`$?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$?).  But it can be more convenient to use a wrapper:

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw(capture $EXITVAL EXIT_ANY);

my @output = capture([0,2], "$myexe 2>&1");
print @output;
print "Program exited with value $EXITVAL\n";
```

The `[0,2]` says that exit values 0 or 2 are expected, and anything else is a fatal error; you can use `EXIT_ANY` instead.

This does get all the output at the end, rather than when it is produced, though.